# How to force close of bootbox.alert() on an outside of modal click?

Tags: bootbox

How to force close of bootbox.alert() on an outside of modal click? Ideally without jQuery.

I am using Bootbox v4.4.0.

Comment: Bootbox relies on bootstrap.js, which in turn relies on jQuery. So... why "ideally without jQuery"?

Answer (score 7):

You can specify this behavior when creating your alert, using the [`backdrop` option](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-dialog-options).

Example:

```js
bootbox.alert({
    message: 'This is an alert!',
    backdrop: true
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

The default for that option is `null`, which means clicking on the backdrop does nothing. Passing `false` removes the backdrop, and passing `true` shows the backdrop and makes clicking on it dismiss the dialog.